Attach image via UIActivityViewController to gmail "Unable to attach the operation couldn't be completed.(com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)"
I'm encountering an issue when trying to share an image via UIActivityViewController to Google services like Gmail, GChat, Google Drive in my iOS app.
I receive the following error:

Unable to attach the operation couldn't be completed.(com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)

func asImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
    self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
    }

    @objc func shareImage() {
    let viewImage = shareableImageWrapperView.asImage()

    // Ensure the image is not nil
    guard let image = viewImage else {
        print("Error: Image is nil")
        return
    }

    // Create the activity view controller
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)

    // Exclude types of activities that you don't want to present
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .postToFacebook]

    // For iPad: present the activity view controller as a popover
    if let popoverPresentationController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []
    }

    // Present the activity view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Context

The asImage function converts a view into a UIImage.
The shareImage function creates an UIActivityViewController to share this image.
Sharing via native Mail works fine, but sharing via Gmail results in the mentioned error.

Desired Outcome
I want the sharing functionality to work correctly with Gmail, similar to how it works with native Mail.
Any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
